# Swapping views in a window

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile

I am building a Titanium Android mobile app using Titanium Studio, build: 3.1.2.201306061831 and testing on an HTC EVO and building it on my MacBook Pro 10.7.5.

This is a tabbed application, when the tab is selected a tableview with rows of choices appears, when a row is selected, a URL is sent to a remote server and database so JSON data can be retrieved.

I had this working by having the tableview and creating the HTTP client in two separate files and displaying the JSON in a new window on top of the tableview. This worked, but my tabs were not visible.

I read that I should try hiding and showing the views in the tabbed window. The first view displays properly and then when a row is selected the view is no longer visible but the new view never shows up. This is how I did it:

```
var tableview = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    top:'50dp',
    visible:'true', 
    color: '#000', 
    contentHeight:'auto'}
);
//My table code
tableview.addEventListener('click', function(e)
    {
        if(checkInternetConnection()){      
                tableview.visible='false';          
                    var communityview=Ti.UI.createView({
                    top:'10dp'
    });
    communityview.visible='true';
//Create the HTTPClient
//add everything to communityview and add communityview to the window
```

Did I mess up how I did my code?

Comment: `tableview.visible` should a boolean value not string, same for `communityview.visible`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small mistake in your code. The [property visible](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-visible) of TiUIView is a boolean value. In your code you have given it as a string value by using `single quotes(')`. Your code will work properly if you remove the single quotes and rewrite the code as follows

```
var tableview = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    top:'50dp',
    visible:true, 
    color: '#000', 
    contentHeight:'auto'}
);
//My table code
tableview.addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
    if(checkInternetConnection()){      
        tableview.visible=false;          
        var communityview=Ti.UI.createView({
        top:'10dp'
    });
    communityview.visible=true;
    }
});
```

I hope this helped you

Comment: I ended up using `tableview.hide();` and `communityview.show();` Thank you Anand.